# How do I add delay within a function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I am trying to create a simple function when on click a series of style changes happen to an element.

I want to add a 4-second delay in between the two style changes that I make. I've found a few methods of adding delays before and after a function but not inside a function how can I achieve this?

My Code:

```
const btnEl = document.getElementById("btnel")
const subtl = document.getElementById("chp1sub")

document.getElementById("chp1sub").style.backgroundColor = "red";

btnEl.addEventListener("click", function(){
    subtl.style.backgroundColor = "blue"
    
// 4 second delay here before running next line

    subtl.style.transform = "translateY(-90px)"
})
```

Would really appreciate any advice on this

Comment: Its called "timers": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout

Comment: You could get the delay implemented via CSS animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the `setTimeout` method, it runs a function after the time you set in milliseconds. To achieve what you need, you have to set an anonymous function to it.

[More information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout)

### Example

```
setTimeout(() => {
  /* Code to run after 4 seconds */
}, 4000)
```

### With your code

```
const btnEl = document.getElementById("btnel")
const subtl = document.getElementById("chp1sub")

document.getElementById("chp1sub").style.backgroundColor = "red";

btnEl.addEventListener("click", function(){
  subtl.style.backgroundColor = "blue"
    
  setTimeout(() => {
    // 4 second delay here before running next line
    subtl.style.transform = "translateY(-90px)"
  }, 4000)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use CSS transition-delay inside that function

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Create an anonymous inner function called by [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout)

```js
const btnEl = document.getElementById("btnel")
const subtl = document.getElementById("chp1sub")

document.getElementById("chp1sub").style.backgroundColor = "red";

btnEl.addEventListener("click", function(){
    subtl.style.backgroundColor = "blue"
    
    setTimeout(function(){
        subtl.style.transform = "translateY(-90px)"
    },4000)
})
```

Alternately, because this is a CSS transition, you can use [CSS transition-delay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay) with this translation.